# How to fix an error during GitHub Action workflow run when deploying website

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions

I'm trying to deploy my first website to hostinger and everything was working fine, here is the plink to the repo: https://github.com/AlexPowellDev/portfolio. You can see there is no build branch on github but that is because it is created on hostinger. I added the webhook and deploy key to GitHub. [image]
Until I made a workflow as follows:

```yaml
name: Generate a build and push to another branch 

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    name: Build and Push
    steps:
      - name: git-checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install all dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build # The build command of your project

      - name: Push
        uses: s0/git-publish-subdir-action@develop
        env:
          REPO: self
          BRANCH: build # The branch name where you want to push the assets
          FOLDER: dist # The directory where your assets are generated
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # GitHub will automatically add this - you don't need to bother getting a token
          MESSAGE: "Build: ({sha}) {msg}" # The commit message
```

And this is the error I receive when the workflow runs:

[image: error]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Do I need to change the branch name back to `master`? I'm not sure if I made it more complicated than it needed to be. I can also add more info if needed. Thanks!

Comment: I tried changing the branch to "master"  which you can see here: [link] (https://imgur.com/sk3Paz6) but that did not work either. I then created a build branch in my repo and this error still shows up:  Error: no such file or directory: /home/runner/work/portfolio/portfolio/dist/. so im not sure whats wrong besides not having that dir. I dont know why its even pointing there.

Comment: Wait. It is already creating a new branch if one does not exist. But, it is unable to find the `dist` directory what is built on the `master` branch. It makes sense.

Comment: The only thing remains is to verify your `dist` directory whether it exists or not. Please try to figure that out using `pwd` and `ls` after build step e.g. `npm run build && pwd && ls -l`.

Comment: Yeah i dont see it there. This is all the folders  shown:                                               .github
build
 node_modules
 public
 src
 .gitignore
 package-lock.json
package.json
 README.md

Comment: That's the problem. You need to verify the logs of your build step. The repo you linked is private (https://github.com/AlexPowellDev/portfolio) so I can't look at the logs.

Comment: There's a `build` directory in above listing. What's in that? Check with `ls -l build`.

Comment: Just some boilerplate files i think from when i made the build branch manually:         static
 asset-manifest.json
favicon.ico
 index.html
 logo192.png
 logo512.png
 manifest.json
robots.txt

Comment: You can check the timestamps of these files. From `index.html`, looks like it's the site that you're trying to deploy. You need to verify these.

Comment: I made my repo public, so that might help. Also thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: From the build [logs](https://github.com/AlexPowellDev/portfolio/actions/runs/4561448301/jobs/8047413636#step:4:14), it is indeed generating in `build`. So, your config should be `FOLDER: build`.

Comment: Thanks. That helped.I did change the Folder to build, it creates a new branch and then pushes those changes to that branch. The file manager on hostinger has the incorrect files attached but the website is functional for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your actual build folder is `build` in the build step but the configured folder that you're deploying from is `dist`:

```
FOLDER: dist
```

You need to configure it accordingly:

```
FOLDER: build
```

For future reference, you should always verify whether the generated artifacts are indeed present or not e.g. by using `ls` command to check the contents of your target folder.